# Calculating the expected value of a function of a random variable

Tags: probability-theory

Suppose $\Omega$ is countable. Let $X : \Omega \to \mathbb{R} $ be a r.v and suppose $T $ is the range of $X$. I know that

$$ \mathbb{E} \{ X \} = \sum_{j \in T} j P(X = j) $$

But, what if we have, say instead of $X$, another r.v: $X^2$ or $|X+ \alpha |$, then to compute the expected value of these r.v., should we just compute

$$ \mathbb{E} \{ X^2 \} = \sum_{j \in T } j P(X^2 = j ) $$

$$ \mathbb{E} \{ |X + \alpha| \} = \sum j P( |X + \alpha| = j ) $$ ??

This question arises because I am trying to compute the following: if $X$ is poisson with parameter $\lambda > 0$, then I want to find $\mathbb{E} \{ |X - \lambda| \} $. I get suck because

$$ \mathbb{E} \{ |X - \lambda| \} = \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} j P( |X - \lambda| = j ) $$

and I cant compute these easily. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician

Comment: Also, the title of this question has nothing to do with your question; your question isn't about notation. I'd suggest revising.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, you need to take into account that the new random variable may have a different range. For example, if $X$ takes value $-1$ then $X^2$ is $1$. So, if you have for your original random variable
$$
E(X)=\sum_{j\in T}jP(X=j),
$$
then for $Y=X^2$ you have
$$
E(Y)=\sum_{k\in R}kP(Y=k)=\sum_{j\in T}j^2P(X=j)=E(X^2).
$$
Therefore, if you have a function $f$ of a random variable $X$ then its expectation is
$$
E(f(X))=\sum_{j\in T}f(j)P(X=j).
$$

Comment: in 5th line, How do you get your second equality ?

Comment: Say, you have $-2$ and $2$ in the range of $X$ with probabilities $p_{-2}$ and $p_2$. Therefore, in the range of $Y=X^2$ you will have $4$ with the probability $p_{-2}+p_{2}$. Generalize.

Comment: Got it. So to see if I have understood: Say $X$ is poisson ($\lambda$). then, $$E ( |X - \lambda |) = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} |i - \lambda| p_i = \sum_{i \geq \lambda} (i - \lambda) p_i + \sum_{i < \lambda} (\lambda - i) p_i $$ correct ?

Comment: Why do you count from $i=1$?

Comment: sorry, typo, just fixed it

Comment: Yes, it is correct now.

Comment: One last question: In the setting of my previous comment, can I argue as follows: $$ \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} (i - \lambda) p_i = \sum i p_i - \lambda \sum p_i = E(X) - \lambda \cdot 1 = \lambda - \lambda = 0 $$ Is this correct ?

Comment: No, you do not have $\sum ip_i$ term.

Comment: Isnt $\sum i p_i $ just the expectation ?

Comment: Watch the signs of your expressions. What you write is $E(X-\lambda)$ not $E(|X-\lambda|)$

Comment: I understand, but do we have that $E( X - \lambda) $ is just $0$ ?